# How do I append data all into one dialog box?

Tags: java, getter

I have a problem with my address book program.  I view all the entries from my address book, but they are displayed in different dialog boxes.  The first entry will be displayed in the first dialog box and then if i click "OK" the next entry will be shown in another dialog box.  I want all entries to be shown in one dialog box.

here's my getter method:

```
public String getInfo(){
        String Info = "NAME\tADDRESS\tPHONE NO.\tE-MAIL ADD\n" +
                name +"\t " + add +"\t "+ phoneNo +"\t "+ email +"\n";
        return Info;
    }
```

here's how i display all information:

```
public void viewAll() {
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JTextArea(entry[i].getInfo()));
        }
    }
```

hope you can help me... thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do this, do not know what...this is your question

Comment: That's just what I would expect looking at your code. You loop through all the entries and show each one in its own message dialog. What was your intention? What is not behaving the way you expect?

Comment: What you've said it does currently, is exactly what you've told it to do. Crucially, you haven't told us what you **want** it to do. More info please!

Comment: -1 This question is not helpful to the SO community.  It does not define a problem well, and the accepted answer doesn't explain the problem either.  It's not clear what this question or answer is about.

Comment: Edited the question for clarity.  Removed my downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to view all the entries inside one dialog box, you can try creating a string     that will add up all the entries. See my code below:

```
 public String getInfo() {
   String content = "\t" + name + "\t"+ address + "\t\t" + telNo + "\t" + email;
   return content;
}


public class AddressBook
 public void viewAllEntry() {
        String addText = "NO\tNAME\tADDRESS\t\tTEL.NO\tEMAIL\t\n"; /<------HERE
        for (int i = 0; i <  addressBookEntryCounter; i++) {
            addText = addText+(i+1)+ entry[i].getInfo()+ "\n";     /<------HERE
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JTextArea(addText));
    }

}
```

You could also try **ninesided**'s solution

Answer (score 2):

I'll take a wild stab in the dark here - you want ALL the contact information to be displayed in the same JOptionPane:

```
public void viewAll() {
    StringBuffer contactList = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        contactList.append(entry[i].getInfo());
        contactList.append("\n");
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JTextArea(contactList));
}
```